# My DBUtil is unable to INSERT data to MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Hello I connect to MySQL DB correctly I am able to display all the data but I am not able to INSERT any value with using my class:

```
 public void addBook(Book theBook) throws Exception {

    Connection myConn = null;
    PreparedStatement myStmt = null;

    try {
        myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

        String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `rezerwacje_miejsc` "
                + "(`NR_MIEJSCA`, `START`, `KONIEC`, `IMIE_NAZWISKO`, `TELEFON`) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

        myStmt.setInt(1, theBook.getNumber());
        myStmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(theBook.getStart().getTime()));
        myStmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(theBook.getEnd().getTime()));
        myStmt.setString(4, theBook.getUserName());
        myStmt.setInt(5, theBook.getPhone());

        myStmt.execute();

    } finally {

        close(myConn, myStmt, null); 
    }
}
```

I've got no errors just no INSERT on DB (also checked manually on phpMyAdmin to make sure it is not .jsp display issue, then I was trying to check my query but it seems to be ok. I am running out of ideas

Comment: `myStmt.execute()` should return a `boolean` value. Make it an `if` condition to see what the result is. For instance `if(myStmt.execute()){ System.out.println("success"); }`

Comment: Where do I can check that output while running web app and sending the form from index.html? :)

Comment: if you do a `System.out`, you'd check in the console of wherever you are running the java code, like the IDE you used to write it or the console of the server hosting it.

Comment: Do you have any commits in your code?

Comment: No, I didn't use any repository :(
I am in a dead end - I can't find the cause of it why that insert query does not work. And worse I have no idea for now, what more I could check :(

Comment: I've tried sop on myStmt.execute() but Netbeans doesn't display anything in output console. I've tried display string "success" for true and "fail" for false, and all i get is: https://gyazo.com/428d44226ec61dae4f4c7ba5c5e9fe17

Comment: Or run nyStmt.executeUpdate()

Comment: Ok, guys, I found the solution. I have a bug in my HTML form so the Java code has nothing to do with it. Thanks for all help! :)